It's illegal for a search engine to censor search results purely of maliciousness?
If a search engine censors search results because their owners don't like these things, is this illegal? E.g. censoring search results about movies and TV shows that their owners dislike.

No
If a search engine owner wanted to censor their results,  providing the reason is not unlawful discrimination (e.g. based on the user’s race, gender etc.), no problem.
If fact, this is how social media searches work - they direct you to the things that will serve the owner’s interest. Mostly this is to things that they think you will like, OT make you angry, but the could have an agenda and instead direct you to the things they like.

What about the race, gender etc. of the content being censored? E.g. weeding out artists of a certain race from the results?

@Greendrake !

Would you care to comment how it would be illegal if it was based on a protected characteristic?  At least gender is used by google.

It's illegal to refuse service based on protected characteristic, but it's not illegal to provide curated service based on the consumers' characteristics. Generally, it would not be as efficient to show tampon ads to males than to females, and ad companies would want to optimize for maximum conversion rates. So, would you care to comment why that would be illegal?

@littleadv: I'll offer Samantha Liapes vs Facebook Inc. as evidence that ad-targeting based on protected characteristics is not necessarily legal.

Interesting. This seems to specifically rely on a California law, and "Liberally construing the complaint and drawing all reasonable inferences in favor of Liapes's claims". However in this case the topic was not something that on its own is gender specific (insurance, as opposed to feminine hygiene in my example).

@Brian You should post that as an answer.

Although discriminating based on the class of the user is different from discriminating based on the search engine operator's opinion of the material. E.g. you can create a search engine that doesn't return pro-Trump material.

@Barmar: OP is asking about censorship based on the censor's preference, rather than based on protected characteristics.  So, I don't think the case I mentioned is a good answer to OP's question.

@Brian Agreed, as I said in my 2nd comment.
